# Improving H2 performance for tests

Tags: unit-testing, h2

We're using H2 as a fast in-memory DB. To isolate the tests from one another we drop and recreate the entire DB schema after every test. It works quite fast, but not fast enough.

1. Is there a way in (in memory) H2 to create a 'global' (not transaction) save point to easily keep returning to it after every test?
2. Is there a way to perform a **binary** dump to the DB to improve the recreation process?

Thanks!